# Can't select rows individually without grouping

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, select

I have an SQL query that is supposed to grab programme, class and year from my Students Table, given two columns X and Y of numbers. If x=3 and Y=4, for instance, it means there's a connection between student 3 and 4 and I will select programme, class, year from student 4, for the sake of our argument.

The problem is, if there are two rows in which X and Y are equal, for example :
    Row 1: X=3, Y=4
    Row 2: X=3, Y=4

(because maybe there are two connections), the SELECT will only select programme, class, and year just ONCE, not twice. I want it to select that repetion individually, so my loop later will echo that twice.

I hope I made myself clear!

```
$SQL = "
  SELECT Programme, Class, Year 
  FROM Students
  WHERE  Student_ID in (
    SELECT X
    FROM SearchStudent
    WHERE Y= '$id'
  )";
```

Comment: Try a JOIN instead, it'll probably faster in most cases too.

Comment: mm ok, how would I structure it?

Comment: posted an example as an answer

Comment: Your problem is caused because it is selecting only from the `Students` table. There is only one row in the `Students` table with each Student_ID so no matter how many are in `SearchStudent`, you only get one row in the output (for each value). The test merely qualifies each row in `Students` as include or exclude. As @Uueerdo says, use a JOIN if you want all combinations.

Comment: I'll try to expain better. The second part of my SQL query works, it creates a table with all relevant rows, some equal, some not. What I want is like a loop, which tells it to go through all those rows I just created, and find one of those values in my other table Students, and select Programme, Class and Year for that value. For instance: row1: 3,4. Select Programme, Class and Year from Students where studid=4.
Row2: 3,4. Select AGAIN Programme, class and year from students where studid=4. You see?

Comment: Are you doing making the query from a php script? It might help if you include that

Comment: @Nockingam there are no real "row numbers" in MySQL, or (I believe) most RDBMSes. You can somewhat emulate such behavior in MySQL with `LIMIT [number of results], [offset from first]`; but without a fully qualified `ORDER BY` clause, that is not 100% reliable.

Answer (score 1):

The JOIN I mentioned in comment will probably look something like this:

```
SELECT s.Programme, s.Class, s.Year 
FROM SearchStudent AS ss
INNER JOIN Students AS s ON ss.X = s.Student_ID
WHERE ss.Y= '$id'
;
```

*And don't forget to sanitize your inputs (i.e. make sure $id has no `'` in it); or better, look into parameterized queries*